# How to migrate events from the frame_system pallet?

Tags: storage-migration, frame-system

I am trying to migrate the events storage value of the `frame_system pallet`, this is required  because the `EventRecord` is now a generic over `RuntimeEvent` instead of `Event`, but I am not sure of how to go about it as I don't know where the `RuntimeEvent` and `Event` types are defined. Has anyone performed this migration?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events storage never needs to be migrated since it is cleared every block.

Further, the change from `Event` to `RuntimeEvent` was just a rename ([#11981](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11981)) of the type.

Comment: Thanks! Is the blockWeight storage item of the same pallet also cleared with every block? Or does it require a migration?

Comment: It is also cleared, as you can see [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/9a111fdc6ed81506033efe29920161f55a34a151/substrate/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L1513).

Comment: Thanks for your help!